# Nginx 301 Permanent Redirect For Language Support

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am now enabling language support for my web site.  I am including the language as part of the URL.  For example: domain.com/**en**/page  I need to setup 301 redirects for existing search engine indexing.

The following works in Nginx to redirect from **domain.com/blog** to **domain.com/en/blog**

```
location = /blog {
    return 301 /en/blog;
}
```

I don't understand the redirect needed to go from domain.com/blog/read/# to **domain.com/en/blog/read/#** (where # is the sequence field in a postgres database table)

I have spent time looking, searching and reading docs to find this answer myself.  I am not understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prefix the existing requested URI with `/en` you can use:

```
return 301 /en$request_uri;
```

The above will add the three characters before the existing request and also include any arguments that may be present.

To match any URI that begins with `/blog`, use `location /blog { ... }`. To match any URI that begins with `/blog/read/` use `location /blog/read/ { ... }`.

Nginx chooses a location to process a request based on a [set of rules](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location). So, you will need to consider the other `location` blocks present within your configuration.

Comment: This has only partially worked. There are re-directs happening, but not for all that I had expected.  What is confusing me is **location /blog { ... }** works for all URL's starting with **/blog** (regardless of how long).  I've only needed (1) **location** entry.  So I tried to create the same for **/video**.  **/video** redirects to **/en/video**.  But **/video/presentation/343** doesn't re-direct.  I don't understand why blog works for any length of URL (example: **/blog/read/2019/5/25/10/30**) but not any length of video URL's